# Can a windows client access the server registry when RPC is already opened? RPC is already open as in a case when printer is shared

Tags: c++, c, server, client, registry

Can a windows client access the server registry when RPC is already opened?
RPC is already open as in a case when printer is shared.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What does RPC have to do with Registry access?  What problem are you having exactly? Please clarify your question.  As it stands, it is a bit too broad and likely to be closed as such.

Comment: Thanks Remy.My question to rephrase again:Can we access the server registry from client, as in open the registry and read the registry value in the server.

Comment: That is a different question than what you originally asked. You should have either [edited your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40292414/edit) to rewrite it (not posted it as a comment), or else closed it and posted a new question.  In any case, yes you can access and read/write the Registry of a remote server. See the [`RegConnectRegistry()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724840.aspx) function.